# Where do Kaggle Masters Work?

Tags: kaggle

If you become a Kaggle Grand Master, it should increase your job prospects, but does it guarantee a job at a FANG company for instance is a question of interest.

Answer (score 2):

In [1] Kaggle published top competition performers and [2] is a dataset of the Top 100 competitors. Using this information and more, this list includes the top 10 institutions hiring the best Kagglers.

1- Nvidia.
2- Microsoft.
3- Kaggle.
4- Amazon.
5- Layer6 AI.
6- Samsung Electronics.
7- Upwork.
8- IBM.
9- Toyota.
10-Google.

However, while these companies hired from the top Kagglers, combined they hired no more than 5% of the top Kagglers.

[1] https://www.kaggle.com/rankings?group=competitions

[2] https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/vivovinco/kaggle-competitions-top-100